# Show Wordpress Category Based on Category Name's Content

Tags: wordpress

I need to show a list of Wordpress categories only if the category name begins with an "*" (asterisk).

I know I can display the list of categories based on some criteria using the template tags:

```
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
```

What I don't know how to do is write the if statement that checks to see if the category name starts with an *.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you may try this

```
global $wpdb;
$query = SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( wp_terms.term_id ) AS IDS FROM wp_term_relationships LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id ) LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy =  'category' AND wp_terms.name LIKE  '*%'
$ids = $wpdb->get_var($query);
wp_list_categories("include=$ids");
```